# Robots.txt and specific file inclusion

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Is it possible to use robots.txt to disallow crawling of a folder, but allow crawling a specific file in that folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[At the very bottom of the page](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

> **To exclude all files except one**
>
> This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field.
> The easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate directory,
> say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this directory.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex answer is partially correct. I subsequently discovered this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive